# "Hear" or "Hearing"

Tags: present-continuous

Is this correct that we can't say. "I am hearing the sound" gramatically because 'hear' is a state verb but,'i hear the sound',is correct.
But can i say that 'i hear the sound' is a continous tense sentence. Even though it has no +ing form in it.

Comment: This is difficult, because 'I can hear [the tap dripping in the kitchen]' is the usual idiomatic choice. Punctive (notionally happening in an instant {in practice, a short time: _Jill hit Jack_ / _They climbed the peak_}) vs durative (notionally lasting a length of time: _Winter was drawing on_  / _They were climbing the peak_) are probably better ways to look at duration of events / processes. Both "I am hearing a faint whining sound" (durative) and "I heard a gunshot" (punctive) are quite acceptable.

Answer (score 1):

Both are correct, depending on the context. For example, if asked to, "Tell me when you can hear something as I change the volume," you could respond, "I'm hearing the sound now." ["Now" is optional, but often used in this context.]

However, throughout your question, *you've ignored capitalization of the personal pronoun, "I"*. That is unacceptable in written English.